# obj formatted to json using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I am using jqCloud plugin to generate word clouds. This script relies on the json to be formatted in a particular pattern. I am trying to get `var msg` parsed out as json like it is in the `var word_array`

```
$(function() {
        var count = 3;
        $.wordStats.computeTopWords(count, $('body'));
        var msg = 'Top words:\n';
        for (var i = 0, j = $.wordStats.topWords.length; i < j && i <= count; i++) {
            msg += '\n' + $.wordStats.topWords[i].substring(1) + ': ' + $.wordStats.topWeights[i];
        }
        console.log(msg);
        //this is what gets printed in the console
        //Top words:
        //bag: 46
        //tote: 30
        //ugh: 30

        $.wordStats.clear();

        // I am trying to get var msg to spit out json
        // that is formatted like this

 var word_array = [{
                text: "Lorem",
                weight: 15
            }, {
                text: "Ipsum",
                weight: 9,
                link: "http://jquery.com/"
            }, {
                text: "Dolor",
                weight: 6,
                html: {
                    title: "I can haz any html attribute"
                }
            }
            // ...as many words as you want
        ];
        $('#example').jQCloud(word_array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an object and stringify it afterward although you maybe dont need to and can just feed the object straight away to jQCloud.

```
    var json_obj = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = $.wordStats.topWords.length; i < j && i <= count; i++) {
        var w = {};
        w.text = $.wordStats.topWords[i].substring(1);
        w.weight = $.wordStats.topWeights[i];
        json_obj.push(w);
    }
    var msg = JSON.stringify(json_obj);
```

Comment: Thanks,  this gets me much closer but I now get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'weight' of [ ` seems like it is unable to drill into the array and interprets the opening bracket as the first object.

Comment: The error is happen when you feed the object to jqcloud?

Comment: Per charlietfl's comment I moved    `$.wordStats.clear();` to the bottom and it now works. Thanks All!! I Upvoted charlietfl comments but chose this answer to avoid manually creating json.

Answer (score 2):

You are manually creating strings that provide no benefit toward trying to meet your output needs.

The data structure you are looking for is an array of objects. This map should give you what you need

```
var word_array= $.wordStats.topWords.map(function(item, index){
    return { text: item.substring(1) , weight:  $.wordStats.topWeights[index] };
});

$('#example').jQCloud(word_array);
```

Hint:  never try to manually create JSON...it is highly error prone. Create arrays and/or objects and if you really need that as JSON convert th whole structure. In this case you need an actual array ...not JSON

Comment: Thanks for the tip on manually creating json, good to know!! I tried your snippet and recieve this error in console. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null`

Comment: did you place this where your `for` loop is and before `clear()`. Also important to know what line that error came from and what file. Could be the next plugin or this code or ??